# MVC 3 - css is not rendering

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my fault because I messing with two css files. So I deleted both css files from the content folder. Replaced it again with just one Site.css file. Updated in _Layout.cshtml file, from shared folder, like so...

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

So now it is not updating. Just getting plain outlook, when runnung the program. Also tried with with Site.Master in shared folder...no luck, don't know where else to look.

Any sugguestion?

Comment: Found the answer? Post it as an answer.

Comment: @BoltClock @DiscoDude says: _I had to wait for 8 hours to post as answer, as per message from Stack Overflow. In other words the system wouldn't let me do it. It was getting little late so left it for following day._

Comment: Those restrictions start going away once you get higher reputation. Mark your answer as the solution, as to close this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I removed `_ViewStart.cshtml` in views folder. So I created one and its seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Getting message that I have to wait till tomorrow to accept my own anwer. Had lots of points but gave them away to solve a question.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue tonight and I found that even though my Content\Site.css file did start with a capital "S", in my layout I had to use a lower "s" (Content\site.css) for my stylesheet to show up properly in IE.  In Chrome it worked fine either way.

Comment: The issue was probably that IE was caching your style sheet.  Changing the casing of the "S" just made IE think it's a new style sheet so it didn't use the cached one. Bet if you change the style sheet again, it will seem that IE isn't taking it again.  You could have also done a Shift-Reload in IE (hold the Shift key down and click the page refresh icon).  That forces the cache for that page to be flushed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue:
Please give permissions to:  IIS_USR and IUSR to your website folder.  It will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the reference to your stylesheet starts with the tilde character.  For example:

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you don't specify the leading "~/", then the server won't be able to find the CSS file when you reference a page directly.  For example, wwww.myserver.com/Home/Index won't work, but www.myserver.com will.